# Django Bootstrap modal edit not showing data on inputs

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-modal, crud

I am developing a Django application to store customers data with a CRUD. I decided to use bootstrap modals to Add, edit info and delete a new customer. Therefore, I'm dealing with some problems when I try to open the **edit modal**. When the edit customer modal is opened the **customer information** that was clicked on **is not appearing in the input fields** of the form. Below I will show the pieces of my code in question, which are being used in this feature

My base template is "**meus-clientes.html**" and the button to show the edit modal, is inside the table:

```
                        <div>
                            <div class="card mb-4" id="tabela-pedidos">
                              <div class="card-header">
                                  <div>
                                      <i class="fas fa-user-tie"></i>
                                      Clientes cadastrados
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="card-body">
                                  <table id="datatablesSimple2">
                                      <thead>
                                          <tr>
                                            <th>Nome</th>
                                            <th>Telefone</th>
                                            <th>E-mail</th>
                                            <th>CPF</th>
                                            <th>Endereço</th>
                                            <th>Pagamento</th>
                                            <th>Ações</th>
                                          </tr>
                                      </thead>
                                      <tfoot>
                                          <tr>
                                            <th>Nome</th>
                                            <th>Telefone</th>
                                            <th>E-mail</th>
                                            <th>CPF</th>
                                            <th>Endereço</th>
                                            <th>Pagamento</th>
                                            <th>Ações</th>
                                          </tr>
                                      </tfoot>
                                      <tbody>
                                          {% for dados_cliente in dados_clientes %}
                                          <tr>
                                              <td>{{ dados_cliente.nome }}</td>
                                              <td>{{ dados_cliente.telefone }}</td>
                                              <td>{{ dados_cliente.email_1 }}</td>
                                              <td>{{ dados_cliente.cpf }}</td>
                                              <td>{{ dados_cliente.endereco }}</td>
                                              <td>{{ dados_cliente.metodo_pagamento }}</td>
                                              <td>
                                                <div class="action-link">
                                                    <a title="Editar cliente" href="{% url 'editar_cliente' dados_cliente.id %}">
                                                        <i class="fas fa-pen"></i>
                                                    </a>
                                                    <a data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#deleteModal{{ dados_cliente.id }}" title="Excluir Cliente">
                                                        <i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i>
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>
                                              </td>
                                          </tr>
                                          {% include 'editar-cliente.html' %}

                                          {% include 'delete-modal.html' %}

                                          {% endfor %}
                                          
                                      </tbody>
                                  </table>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
```

The edit customer modal which name is "**editar-cliente.html**" is shown below:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal{{ dados_cliente.id }}" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h2 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Editar cliente</h2>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form method="post" action="/editar_cliente" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
            {% csrf_token %} 
                {{cliente.id}}
                {% for field in form %}
                  <div class="form-field">
                    {{ field.label_tag }} 
                    {{ field }} 
                    {% if field.errors %}
                      <p class="error-message">{{ field.errors.as_text }}</p>
                    {% endif %}
                    <p>Valor do campo: {{ field.value }}</p>
                  </div>
                {% endfor %}
                <div class="customer-button-modal">
                  <button class="botao-voltar-customer" data-bs-dismiss="modal">
                    Voltar
                  </button>
                  <button type="submit" class="add-customer-button">Salvar Alterações</button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My "**forms.py**" file where the class "**AddCustomerForm**" is included:

```
def validate_cpf(value):
    # Custom CPF validator
    if not value.isdigit() or len(value) != 11:
        raise ValidationError('CPF deve conter exatamente 11 números.')

def validate_phone(value):
    # Custom phone number validator
    if not value.isdigit() or len(value) != 11:
        raise ValidationError('Informe um telefone válido com DDD.')
    
class AddCustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    nome = forms.CharField(
        label='Nome do cliente',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'input-form-customer',
            'placeholder': 'José da Silva'
        }),
        required=True
    )
    cpf = forms.CharField(
        label='CPF do cliente',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'input-form-customer',
            'placeholder': 'XXX.XXX.XXX-XX'
        }),
        required=False,
        validators=[validate_cpf]
    )
    email_1 = forms.EmailField(
        label='E-mail do cliente',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'input-form-customer',
            'placeholder': 'josedasilva@exemplo.com'
        }),
        required=False,
        validators=[EmailValidator]
    )
    endereco = forms.CharField(
        label='Endereço do cliente',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'input-form-customer',
            'placeholder': 'Av. Brasil, 123 - Centro, 13.333-003'
        }),
        required=False
    )
    telefone = forms.CharField(
        label='Telefone do cliente',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'input-form-customer',
            'placeholder': '(11)99999-9999'
        }),
        required=True,
        validators=[validate_phone],
    )
    metodo_pagamento = forms.CharField(
        label='Método de pagamento do cliente',
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'input-form-customer',
            'placeholder': 'PIX'
        }),
        required=False
    )
    
    class Meta:
        model = DadosClienteCadatrado
        fields = ['nome', 'cpf', 'email_1', 'endereco', 'telefone', 'metodo_pagamento']
```

The paths on "**urls.py**" file:

```
    path('meus-clientes/', views.meus_clientes_view, name="meus-clientes"),  
    path('adicionar-cliente/', views.add_cliente_view, name="adicionar-cliente"),  
    path('editar-cliente/<int:cliente_id>/', views.edit_cliente_view, name="editar_cliente"),  
    path('deletar-cliente/<int:cliente_id>/', views.delete_cliente_view, name="deletar_cliente"),
```

And finally my "**edit_cliente_view**" function on "**views.py**" file:

```
def edit_cliente_view(request, cliente_id):
    try:
        user = CustomUser.getUser(request)
    except:
        return redirect('database_error')

    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('login')

    if not user.userIsPremium():
        return redirect('planos_disponiveis')

    if not user.usuario_adimplente_ou_tolerancia_de_uso():
        return redirect('payment_debt_out_service')

    user.finance_check(STANDART_PERIOD)

    dados_clientes = get_object_or_404(DadosClienteCadatrado, id=cliente_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddCustomerForm(request.POST, instance=dados_clientes)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('meus-clientes')
    else:
        form = AddCustomerForm(instance=dados_clientes)

    context = {
        'user': user,
        'form': form,
        'cliente': dados_clientes,
        'userIsPremium': user.userIsPremium(),
        'tab_title': 'Editar cliente',
    }

    return render(request, 'editar-cliente.html', context)
```

Here is the part of my code where the problem is. If any good soul can help me, I will be very grateful!